# Reliable centralized logging in Kubernetes/Docker with Elastic Stack

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, docker, kubernetes, syslog

We are setting up a **Kubernetes cluster on CoreOS** to run 50+ different applications (mostly Java apps), each of which produces logs potentially in its own format.

We're looking to **centralise logs** from all containers with the ***Elastic Stack*** (formerly ELK stack), with some specific requirements:

1. **Reliability** in the face of network, container or node failures.
2. **Exactly-once processing** for each log statement. Even if a failure occurred, the solution must remember where it left off and it should continue dispatching logs from that point onwards, once healthy again.
3. Configure **log grokking patterns within the configuration of the pod/replication controller**. We'd like to avoid configuring app-specific patterns in a centralised, common element (e.g. Logstash).

The solution we have come up with is to use:

1. [**Logspout**](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout) to consume Docker logs – forwarding them to a local...
2. [**rsyslog**](http://www.rsyslog.com/) daemon (e.g. `syslog://localhost:514`), which would forward them to a...
3. [**Logstash**](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) instance running in the cluster and exposed via a Kubernetes Service.
4. Logstash would filter and transform the log files based on container ID, and would dispatch the result to Elasticsearch.

Would this solution be reliable? This solution seems to cover all our requirements except for #3 (grokking patterns alongside apps).

Do you have any suggestions? We are open to using Filebeat, fluentd or other components.

Comment: Just curious: Is the default ELK stack not working for you?

Comment: What do you mean by "working"? The Elastic/ELK stack... Integrated with Docker via Filebeat or syslog

Comment: http://blog.raintown.org/2014/11/logging-kubernetes-pods-using-fluentd.html

Comment: Yes, I had come across that. But how would you fulfil requirement #3?

Comment: For #3, running a fluentd side-car container per pod, with custom configuration, might work.

Comment: Of course. But identifying the log files of the containers in the pod is not so easy out of the box.

Comment: Using the fluentd logging driver could work, but it requires assigning a random port to the fluentd sidecar and passing it as a command line option to docker when running the other containers. Any clue if that's possible?